# How can i POST only one element from my object?

Tags: json, angular

Im new on angular and i'm doing different practices, at the moment i have a function for add a comment.

```
    newComment ( issue: Issue, key$: string) {
    let message = JSON.stringify( issue);
    let headers = new Headers ( {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    });
    let url = `${ this.IssueURL }/${ key$ }/comments/.json`;
    return this.http.post ( url, message, { headers } )
    .pipe(map( res => {
      console.log (res.json());
      return res.json();
    }));
  }
```

This function place my object inside a firebase realtime database with the folloing appearence

```
{
  "issues" : {
    "-LT1c3NfNikLhGIx62dC" : {
      "comments" : {
        "-LT1c5_X5X39oyNa7dnZ" : {
          "description" : "nueva",
          "message" : "gol",
          "priority" : "nueva",
          "tittle" : "nueva"
        },
        "-LT1d3WX3WLXLxis9FLB" : {
          "comments" : {
            "-LT1c5_X5X39oyNa7dnZ" : {
              "description" : "nueva",
              "message" : "gol",
              "priority" : "nueva",
              "tittle" : "nueva"
            }
          },
          "description" : "nueva",
          "message" : "dsa",
          "priority" : "nueva",
          "tittle" : "nueva"
        }
      },
      "description" : "nueva",
      "priority" : "nueva",
      "tittle" : "nueva"
    },
    "-LT1cMwbtng9OLelQewB" : {
      "comments" : {
        "-LT1cPAhnm-FV9QtLAHL" : {
          "description" : "Nueva dos",
          "message" : "hahados",
          "priority" : "Nueva dos",
          "tittle" : "Nueva dos"
        }
      },
      "description" : "Nueva dos",
      "message" : "",
      "priority" : "Nueva dos",
      "tittle" : "Nueva dos"
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, i have a collection /comment/ inside /issues/, related to the function addComment(), it fills the whole object inside the collection /comments/. I'n my case at the moment only i want fill it with the message value.

This is caused by in the same view that i enter a commentary i have the other main elements from the object with a getIssue function.

How can i do in order to pass only one element from my object to the indicated collection=?

Any help would be really appreciate.

Thanks.

Kind regards.

Comment: You are stringifying all your Issue object. You can set your message variable to the comment text.

Comment: let messsage = issues.LT1c3NfNikLhGIx62dC.comments.LT1c5_X5X39oyNa7dnZ.message;

You will get the first message of the array. If you want all then you need to do for loop for it.

Comment: You are totally right, it was more simple than i expected. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

```
let messsage = issues.LT1c3NfNikLhGIx62dC.comments.LT1c5_X5X39oyNa7dnZ.message;
```

Using this code you can pass first comment's message and of you want multiple messages then you need to do for loop and get the messages.